# Links not clickable when sent through Django email

Tags: django, email, gmail

When the website sends out emails, it using a `a` tag to create a link. For some reason, gmail (possible other emails as well) does not turn the text the `a` tag contains into a link.

Function for sending emails:

```
def send_main(to, sbj, msg):
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(sbj, msg, '********@gmail.com', to)
    msg.content_subtype = "html"
    msg.send()
```

Paramaters passed to email in shell

```
send_main(['****@gmail.com'], 'test', '<a href="http://www.google.com"/>test</a>')
```

Yet when I execute the line in the python shell, it sends the email but gmail does not recognize the link.

Comment: The docs use `EmailMessage` directly, for the `content_subtype` trick. Could that be the issue? It uses EmailMultiAlternatives for actually attaching 2 payloads

Answer (score 2):

it is not clickable because some mailing site will block href, but this will work in gmail
and to make the link clickable in those site use send_mail instead

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail('Subject', 'http://www.google.com', 'from@example.com',
['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

hope this will work

Comment: but I guess it is not possible to write anchor tag there ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this method:

```
html_content = render_to_string('emails/email_%s.html' % template_name, { parmas })
message = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, html_content, settings.GENERIC_EMAIL_SENDER,[email])
message.attach_alternative(html_content, 'text/html')
message.send()
```

Pass it into a HTML template and call render_to_string - make sure the attachment is 'text/html' and it should work fine.